# How to get custom value from datalist using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-attributes, datalist

Very simple and straight forward. I pre-populated a HTML datalist with values, on the form when I want select the custom value (data-value) and insert it into SQLServer database. This is my example code which is not working. Please help out. HTML5 datalist form creation:

HTML:

```
 <input id="ocorrenciaSetup" list="ocorrenciasListSetup" name="ocorrenciasListSetup" autocomplete="off">
 <datalist id="ocorrenciasListSetup">
      <option data-value="1.1" data-tipo="1" value="SETUP | [1.1]"></option>
      <option data-value="1.10" data-tipo="1" value="CONSERTO NO CLICHE | [1.10]"></option>
 </datalist>
```

Jquery:

```
$('[name=ocorrenciasListSetup]').attr('data-value');
```

Comment: Not sure what that jQuery line is supposed to achieve. Your input field does not have a `data-value` attribute. And not exactly sure what you are even asking for here either. If you are looking for the value the user selected, _after_ they done that - well then read the _value_ of the input field?

Comment: When I call an onclick function coming from a method I would like to get the data-value field that is selected by jquery. Is this possible using jquery?

Comment: You can not access the "selected" value on the datalist element. But what the user selects there, then _becomes_ the value of the associated input field. So read that one then instead ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something like this in an onclick event:

```
var datavalue = $('#ocorrenciasListSetup').find('option[value="' + $('#ocorrenciaSetup').val() + '"]').attr('data-value'));
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1Lpob6q/